# como puedo calcular con onchange y mostrarlo en tabla

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el modal donde tengo un input tipo number y quiero que al aumentar la cantidad se vaya descontando en el stock.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca el extracto del codigo php

```
<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['idterm'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['nombreterm'].'</td> 
                    <td id="cantidad-inicial">'.$row['cantidadterm'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$ml_nuevo.'</td>
                    <td>
                     <input type="number" min="1" max="'.$row['cantidadterm'].'" class="form-control" id="cantidad_'.$row['idterm'].'" name="cantidad" value="1" autocomplete="off" onchange="onQtyChange(this.value);">
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="ingresarproductofactura(\''.$row['idterm'].'\')"><span class="icon-plus"></span></button>
                    </td>  
                    </tr>
```

aca lo que intente hacer

```
function onQtyChange(valor) {
var total = 0;
var cantidad = 0;  
valor = parseInt(valor);

cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad-inicial').innerHTML;
total = (parseInt(cantidad) - parseInt(valor));
if(parseInt(valor) > parseInt(cantidad)){
     document.getElementById('cantidad-inicial').innerHTML = 0;
}else{
    document.getElementById('cantidad-inicial').innerHTML = total;
  }
}
```

Comment: Muéstranos el código y lo que hayas intentado.

Comment: Te invito a hacer el [tour por el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y a leer [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Gerardo ahí coloque lo que intente hacer xd

Comment: Estoy elaborando la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de responder la pregunta y saliéndome un poco del tema te invito a checar [Salir de HTML](http://php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) de la página de PHP ya que veo que estas concatenando todo el HTML y eso al escribir páginas con PHP puede generar algo de ilegibilidad y dificultad al escribir código.

En la parte de Javascript también agregar código "en linea" (inline), de esta forma: `onchange="onQtyChange(this.value);"` se considera una mala practica pero es válido y responderé a tu pregunta en base a esta forma. Aqui te dejo mas información: [Why Should I Avoid Inline Scripting?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting) (Puedes traducirlo del inglés).

Todo lo anterior son solo recomendaciones de mi parte.

Ahora si respecto a tu pregunta primero necesitas hacer modificaciones en tu HTML; para empezar el código PHP aquí no es relevante ya que tu problema es sobre Javascript y no PHP, así que sólo deja el HTML final que se muestra al usuario.

Primero: debes modificar en tu HMTL los id's `cantidad-inicial`, si vas a tener multiples filas recuerda que un id es único y al utilizar `document.getElementById` y tienes varios id's iguales te va a retornar siempre el primero que encuentre. En este caso cambiaremos ese atributo a `class`.

Segundo: a cada celda *Stock* le agregamos un atributo [`data-`](https://www.genbetadev.com/desarrollo-web/atributos-personalizados-en-html5-mas-datos-con-un-simple-data) en este caso lo llamaremos `stock`. ¿Para qué hacer esto? si te fijas en tu código al obtener el stock desde el `innerHTML` este al cambiarlo ya no será el mismo, es decir, el total ya no será igual cada vez que el el input cambie.

y tercero: necesitas modificar `onQtyChange(this.value);` a `onQtyChange(event);` esto nos permite acceder al objeto `event` del elemento que lo llama y esto para poder modificar elementos de la misma fila.

Te dejo el código javascript:

```
function onQtyChange(event) {
    var filaTr = event.target.parentElement.parentNode; // Elemento <tr> (fila actual)
    var stockTd = filaTr.querySelector('.cantidad-inicial'); // Elemento <td> (celda stock)
    var valor = parseInt(event.target.value);
    var cantidad = parseInt(stockTd.dataset.stock);
    var total = (cantidad - valor);
    stockTd.innerHTML = total;
}
```

En el código anterior

`filaTr`: hace referencia al elemento `<tr>`, la fila desde la que se encuentra el `<input/>` al que estamos ingresando los valores.

`stockTd`: es el elemento `<td>`, la celda stock de la fila actual (`filaTr`).

`valor`: al igual que en tu pregunta, el valor del `<input/>`.

`cantidad`: el valor del atributo `data-stock` de la celda `<td>` stock.

y `total` que es el valor que quedaría en el stock.

y el HTML:

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>ML</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Agregar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>PTDLC60</td>
                <td>Producto term DLC 60</td> 
                <td class="cantidad-inicial" data-stock="3">3</td>
                <td>60</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" min="1" max="3" class="form-control" id="cantidad_PTDLC60" name="cantidad" value="1" autocomplete="off" onchange="onQtyChange(event)">
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="onQtyChange('PTDLC60')">
                        <span class="icon-plus"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

y te dejo un [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xocawitipo/1/edit?js,output) para que puedas probar lo anterior.

Comment: gracias por las recomendación y gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: Si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema, puedes marcarla como [aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) dando click en el icono de aceptar(check) que aparece al lado izquierdo de la respuesta que elijas.